# make widget set to home screen after install/first launch?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget, widget, shortcut

I have code to make a shortcut of my application on the home screen when the user firsts opens the application. Is it possible to make it so that the application sets it so that when the user opens the application the shortcut is replaced with the widget?

**This is the code that I am using to set the shortcut**

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
    shortcutIntent.setClassName(".BatteryWidget", "SampleIntent");
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("someParameter", "HelloWorld");

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);


    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue...

Comment: @TacBOsS, I did alot of reading on it so far everyone says its not possible. the user actually has to do it manually. witch is a bummer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, adding widgets to the homescreen doesn't work without user interaction. Let alone deleting/replacing a shortcut.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the reply. i actually found that out on my own i guess i should have posted that

Comment: @Mark Could you please point me to the documentation? Just in case. Thank you in advance  :-)

Comment: There is neither doc which says that it works nor that is doesn't. There is just no API method to do that. And it also makes sense, cause maybe you can replace an icon with a 1x1 widget (in terms of size) but many widgets are bigger than that and require the user to choose a homescreen with enough space for that.